# UWP DataBinding and Ordering: How to bind a control to a Border.child in ListView?

Tags: vb.net, listview, uwp

This is for VB.NET and XAML for UWP.
I am using ListView, MyList with the DataTemplate:

```
 <ListView x:Name="MyList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="{Binding button1.Content}"></Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding col2}"></TextBlock>
                    <Border Child="{Binding button2}"></Border> 
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And I have :
`DataList As New cObservableListBase(Of Item)`, and

```
 Public Class Item
    'List Properties
    Public Property button1 As CustomButton
    Public Property col2 As String
    Public Property button2 As CustomButton
End Class

Public Class CustomButton
    Inherits Button
    Implements IComparable

    Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo
        CompareTo = 0
        If Content > CType(obj, CustomButton).Content Then
            CompareTo = 1
        ElseIf Content < CType(obj, CustomButton).Content Then
            CompareTo = -1
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

And

```
MyList.ItemsSource = DataList

  For i = 65 To 85
      Dim b1 As New CustomButton With {.Content = Convert.ToChar(i)}
      Dim b2 As New CustomButton With {.Content = Convert.ToChar(i)}
      DataList.Add(New Item With {.button1 = b1, .col2 = Convert.ToChar(i), .button2 = b2})
   Next
```

The ListView contains 3 columns and when I order DataList on any of the columns the first 2 columns which was bound on text will be ordered properly but the 3rd column which was bound on the control itself will show different result. 
Note: that the DataList itself is ordering the 3 columns properly but the problem in the listview not showing the 3rd column properly.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug? and how to bind to a control properly?

**Edit:**

I felt I have to Add a small Program to make it easy for anybody wants to try it.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Name="ADD" Content="Add" Click="AddClick" />
        <Button Name="Order" Content="Order" Click="OrderClick"/>

        <ListView x:Name="MyList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="{Binding button1.Content}"></Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding col2}"></TextBlock>
                        <Border Child="{Binding button2}"></Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

and in code behinde:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page
Public DataList As New ObservableCollection(Of Item)
Public Sub AddClick()
    MyList.ItemsSource = DataList
    For i = 65 To 85
        Dim b1 As New CustomButton With {.Content = Convert.ToChar(i)}
        Dim b2 As New CustomButton With {.Content = Convert.ToChar(i)}
        DataList.Add(New Item With {.button1 = b1, .col2 = Convert.ToChar(i), .button2 = b2})
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub OrderClick()
    Static NextOrder As Boolean = False

    Dim Sorted As IOrderedEnumerable(Of Item)
    If NextOrder Then
        Sorted = DataList.OrderBy(Function(p) p.col2)
    Else
        Sorted = DataList.OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.col2)
    End If
    NextOrder = Not NextOrder

    Dim SortedList = Sorted.ToList

    DataList.Clear()
    For i = 0 To SortedList.Count - 1
        DataList.Add(SortedList(i))
    Next
End Sub
End Class
Public Class Item
        'List Properties
        Public Property button1 As CustomButton
        Public Property col2 As String
        Public Property button2 As CustomButton  'or UIElement 
    End Class
Public Class CustomButton
    Inherits Button
    Implements IComparable

    Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo
        Return Content.ToString.CompareTo(CType(obj, CustomButton).Content.ToString)
    End Function
End Class
```

First add list and then try to order it using order button and the issue is in the 3rd column it is not ordered properly. But when dubuging the program I found that DataList have the correct order even in the third column but the issue is in the Listview not showing this correctly!!

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue in my side, and I checked your code. I found your data binding is not good practice, and I rewrite your model class and xamlto make them look concise and clear. Please refer the following.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public UIElement BTNElement { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListView Name="MyList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="{Binding Content}"></Button>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}"></TextBlock>
                <Border Child="{Binding BTNElement}"></Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Usage**

```
MyList.ItemsSource = new List<Item> {
    new Item { Content = "ClickMe", Color = "Red", BTNElement = new Button { Content = "Nico" } },
    new Item { Content = "ClickMe", Color = "Green", BTNElement = new Button { Content = "Kite" } },
    new Item { Content = "ClickMe", Color = "Blue", BTNElement = new Button { Content = "Chuchu" } } };
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, now with your code try to order the listview  by color and you'll see the issue.  Note: I wrote my code and intentionally I've put the same in all three columns to make the issue clear, because when you order by one of the columns using OrderBy of the observableCollection that I used you'll see that the UIElement will change its position and not move with the rest of the row.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I will try.